# Use pexpect to detect end of bash output

Tags: python, bash, pexpect

I am using `pexpect` to run a bash instance:

```
bash = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash")
```

I would like to be able to "expect" the end of this output. At the moment I'm using the following:

```
bash.sendline("ls -ltr")
lines = []
while True:
    try:
        bash.expect("\r\n", timeout=0.1)
        lines.append(bash.before)
    except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
        print "TO"
        break
```

This is effective, however it seems like it would be more efficient to be able to detect the end of the output without needing to wait for pexpect.TIMEOUT.

Comment: How do you expect to detect the end of the output? By the next prompt? By some other marker? By a delay in output?

Comment: Yes - currently it just stops if it doesn't get a new line within 100ms

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I was asking how you *expect* it to stop? What criteria would you *like* it to use instead of a static timeout? How *can* it determine the end of the output?

Comment: Ah I see - I was hoping there was some kind of signal to show that the called process had exited. The other option would be to detect the prompt, although that seems less than elegant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should expect your prompt. 
Say your prompt is "s", your code should be :

```
bash.expect(">")
```

or even set a variable first for your prompt (in case later on you want to change your prompt;))

```
prompt = ">"
bash.expect(prompt)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my this great snippet (set_unique_prompt) in the pxssh.py module of pexpect, here's a modified example:

```
UNIQUE_PROMPT = "\[PEXPECT\][\$\#] "
PROMPT_SET_CSH = "set prompt='[PEXPECT]\$ '"
def set_unique_prompt():
    # expect that the default shell prompt will display at least a "> "
    c.expect('>\s+$')
    c.sendline(PROMPT_SET_CSH)
    i = c.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, UNIQUE_PROMPT], timeout=2)
    if i == 0:
        print(c.before)
        print(c.after)
        raise Exception("couldn't set CSH shell prompt to something unique that we can match on!")

# start new process
c = pexpect.spawn('csh')
set_unique_prompt()
print("started new shell and renamed it's prompt")

c.sendline('start_long_running_command')
while True:
    i = c.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, self.UNIQUE_PROMPT], timeout=5)
    if i:
        break
    else:
        print('command still running')
print('long running command finished')
```

it basically starts a shell (in this case CSH), then it first changes the prompt signature to something we don't expect will be in the command-output (in this case we set it to "[PEXPECT]$ ", then we can EXPECT the unique-prompt, so we know when the shell is done.

For BASH, just change the `PROMPT_SET_CSH` variable to the command BASH uses to change it's prompt-string... pxssh.py recommends `PROMPT_SET_SH = "PS1='[PEXPECT]\$ '"`